# Ícone errado no mat stepper angular

Tags: angular, material

Estou tentando colocar um ícone de edit quando o state é address, mas o ícone mostrado é do primeiro estado.

Eu tentei:

**Primeiro step:**

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
</ng-template>

<mat-step label="Antes de começar..." state="home">
```

..........

**Segundo step**

```
<ng-template matStepperIcon="address">
    <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
</ng-template>

<mat-step label="Dados do seu pet..." [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" state="address">    
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
        </div>
```

Esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O segundo step deveria ser o edit icon mas está com o ícone do primeiro step. Por quê?

Answer (score 0):

Pode não ser o mais intuitivo, mas... quando o Material Step é editável (editable), que é o default, após completar o step e acionar o próximo step, o anterior fica com o ícone de "edit".

No seu caso com o ícone "home" por conta da diretiva matStepperIcon que usou para mudar o ícone que vem por padrão.

Até o momento, o o Material Step utiliza apenas os ícones: 'create', 'edit' e 'done' que podem ser modificados, porém após mudar de step ele usará, somente, o ícone 'edit' ou o 'done' no step anterior.